# Strict inequality in a Hilbert Space

Tags: hilbert-spaces

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert Space and let $x$ and $y$ be two distinct points in $H$ such that $||x|| = ||y|| = 1$. Then show that $||tx+(1-t)y||<1$, where $0<t<1$.

It is pretty clear that any point lying on the line joining two distinct points on a sphere which is not an end-point itself will lie inside the sphere. But I have problem deducing the strict inequality here. We see that:

$$\begin{align} ||tx+(1-t)y||^2 = \langle tx+(1-t)y, tx+(1-t)y\rangle =  t^2||x||^2+2t(1-t)Re\langle x,y\rangle +(1-t)^2||y||^2  \leq (t+(1-t))^2 = 1 \end{align}$$.

So, my question is how to get rid of the equality. I can not argue that $x$ and $y$ are linearly independent as these may be diametrically opposite points (on the sphere) and hence linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a problem about inner products.

The last inequality is actually [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

> $$|\langle x,y\rangle| \le ||x|| \, ||y||$$
>   Equality holds iff $x$ and $y$ are dependent.

However, the given conditions that $x \ne y$ and $||x||=||y||=1$ leave us two possibilities:

- $x$ and $y$ are linearly independent, so
  $$\Re\langle x,y\rangle \le |\langle x,y\rangle| < ||x|| \, ||y|| = 1.$$
  Put this strict inequality into to your step, and you get your desired conclusion.
- $y = kx$:  $||y|| = 1 \implies |k| = 1$

  - in $\Bbb{R}$, that's $x$ and $y$ are on the opposite poles of a unit sphere.  Use the given condition $t \in (0,1)$ to finish this proof.
  - in $\Bbb{C}$, $\Re\langle x,y\rangle=\Re\left(\bar{k}\right) = \Re(k) \le 1$.  Use $x \ne y$ to make the previous inequality *strict*:
    $$||x-y|| = ||(k-1)x|| = |k-1| \ne 0 \implies k \ne 1$$
    Put $\Re\langle x,y\rangle = \Re(k) < 1$ back into your proof, and we're done.

Remarks: When you are stuck, think of which condition(s) is(are) *unused*.

Comment: Your proof works only over the field $\mathbb R$ where linear dependence between $x$ and $y$ implies either $x=y$ or $x=-y$. Over the complex field $\mathbb C$, it does not work.

Comment: @JackT Nice catch!  I've [edit]ed my answer to fix this.

Comment: Thanks a ton! It all makes sense now.